# Did any rabbis say that Adam and Eve did not have sexual intercourse in the garden?

Tags: midrash, sexuality, adam, eve-chava

Rashi as well as other rabbis said that Adam and Eve had intercourse in the garden. However, did any rabbis say that they did not have intercourse before they sinned?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142530/discussion-on-question-by-terjij-kassal-did-any-rabbis-say-that-adam-and-eve-did); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Torah views intimacy between husband and wife as holy of holies, unlike the general teachings of Christianity which view them as sinful and a necessary evil. In light of that, there are a few threads that the relations in 4:1 took place after the expulsion.

The earliest traditional sources giving details of the creation of Adam and Chava and their having relations in the Garden, prior to expulsion come from two places. [Avot of Rabbi Natan 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D%27Rabbi_Natan.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> How was Adam created? In the first hour, his dirt was gathered together. In the second hour, his form was formed. In the third hour, a torso was made. In the fourth hour, his limbs were attached. In the fifth hour, his orifices were opened. In the sixth hour, he was given breath. In the seventh hour, he stood up on his legs. **In the eighth hour, *he was paired with Eve*. In the ninth hour, *he was brought into the Garden of Eden*.** In the tenth hour, he was commanded [not to eat from the tree]. In the eleventh hour, he disgraced himself. In the twelfth hour, he was driven out and left, which fulfills the words of the verse (Psalms 49:13), “Man does not spend even one night in honor.”

And also [Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer 11:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.11.7?lang=bi) which says:

> The day had twelve hours; in the first hour He collected the dust for (the body of) Adam, in the second (hour) He formed it into a mass, in the third (hour) He gave it its shape, in the fourth (hour) He endowed || it with breath, in the fifth (hour) he stood on his feet, in the sixth (hour) he called the (animals by their) names, **in the seventh (hour) *Eve was joined to him (in wedlock)***, in the eighth (hour) they were commanded concerning the fruits of the tree, **in the ninth (hour) *they went up to (their) couch as two and descended as four***, in the tenth (hour) they transgressed His commandment, in the eleventh (hour) they were judged, **in the twelfth (hour) *they were driven forth***, as it is said, "So he drove out the man" (Gen. 3:24).

The comment by Rabbi Eliezer ben Hyrkanus for the ninth hour, that *they went up to their bed as two, and descended as four*, is referring to copulation and reproduction. Pregnancy and birth were without the consequence of the transgression of eating from the fruit yet. Gestation was almost instantaneous and without difficulty. *(It's worth noting that the idea that this is the normal condition for human conception and birth is also found in Talmud and elsewhere in Torah literature.)* Their first two male children (with their accompanying female twins) took place in this hour.

Note, none of the ***following*** explicitly states that they *didn't* have relations before expulsion. But these are later sources than the first two mentioned above. It is more appropriate to assume that these later sources also had access to these first two sources and were familiar with them. So these later comments are emphasizing and contrasting the change of state in regard to procreation prior to and after the expulsion from the Garden of Eden.

Radak is probably the closest to making that point as he writes:

> והאדם ידע את אשתו, seeing that their libido had developed, they
> engaged in marital relations, Chavah became pregnant and gave birth
> after 7 or 9 months.

The others state that the procreation after expulsion was due to the necessity to procreate now that they were mortal:

Rabbeinu Bachaye:

> והאדם ידע את חוה אשתו, “and man had been intimate with his wife
> Chavah, etc.” After Adam had realized that he had been expelled from
> Gan Eden, that death had been decreed for him, and that he would not
> live indefinitely, it became necessary for him to have sexual
> relations with his wife in order to assure himself of children for
> posterity.

Ibn Ezra:

> AND THE MAN. When Adam realized that he would not live forever he saw
> the need of perpetuating the human race. Eve concurred

It seems that in general, there are two holy reasons to engage in relations, one is to increase closeness and oneness between husband and wife (become one flesh - a commandment given *de facto* before the sin). The other is to fulfil the commandment to procreate. The main debate centres around whether the intimacy in the garden also led to pregnancy or they had intimate relations *again* after expulsion.

See this Siftei Chachamim:

> Children were born to him. Rashi used the expression “children were
> born to him” rather than “he knew his wife” because otherwise Rashi
> would be implying that Adam knew her only after he was exiled, not
> before. [And this is not true,] for earlier, on the verse of “This at
> last is bone of my bones...” (2:23), Rashi says: “Adam attempted to
> find a mate amongst all the animals... until he discovered Chavah.”
> This implies that Adam had relations with Chavah at that point. This
> answers another question: How does Rashi know that Adam’s “knowing his
> wife” before he was exiled included conception and birth as well?
> Perhaps it was referring only to relations. The answer is: “This at
> last is bone of my bones...” already taught us that Adam had
> relations. Thus, the verse “The man knew his wife...” perforce
> [includes conception and birth].

**So, to summarise. I am unaware of any Rabbis that *explicitly* state that they didn't engage in relations in the garden before (or even after) the sin, nor would I expect that this would be a point made as it wouldn't be of interest - in Torah, intimacy between husband and wife is considered nothing but holy and good (although like anything holy and good, it can become profaned and corrupted, God forbid).**

Comment: It would probably be appropriate to add text and links to: Avot of Rabbi Natan 1:8 https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D'Rabbi_Natan.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en and Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer 11:7 https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.11.7?lang=bi

Comment: @YaacovDeane thanks. There's a lot to do to achieve that, bli neder I'll try. Feel free to edit my answer and I'll accept

Comment: @YaacovDeane thank you tzaddik 

Comment: As a point of interest, According to the teaching of the Vilna Gaon, careful attention to the details concerning the creation of Adam and Chava are a sign for the coming of Moshiach. 6th day, after the 1st half of that day (post 5500), that the single creation (Moshiach) is divided into 2 parts in the 7th hour, one greater and one lesser, and in the 8th hour  joined in marriage (consider legal  requirements of marriage). In the beginning of the 9th hour they became one flesh, increased and diversified life (like an allusion to resurrection). 10th hour (new Torah from Moshiach).